# override and with generic type parameter

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Play Scala 2.5, I would like to know how to override the invokeBlock method so that I could get the body of request as json.

```
case class AuthenticatedRequest[A](val username: Option[String], val param: Option[String], request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object AuthenticatedAction extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {

    /**
     * logger used to log actions.
     */
    val logger: Logger = Logger("mylogger")

    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: AuthenticatedRequest[A] => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
        request.session.get("username") match {
            case Some(username) => { 
                val param = (request.body.asJson.get \ "param").as[String]
                block(new AuthenticatedRequest(Some(username), Some(param), request)) 
            }
            case None => Future.successful(Results.Forbidden)
        }
    }
}
```

I have to following exception after compiling:

```
value asJson is not a member of type parameter A
[error]                 val param = (request.body.asJson.get \ "param").as[String]
```

Comment: does your request has the header `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: Yes it does contain Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is linked to the fact that your `body`is returning something of generic type `A`, for which the asJson method is not defined.

Unfortunately, you cannot use pattern matching directly to get the type of A, because of type-erasure of Scala (at run time, only the class exists, not its type parameters). One work-around is to use the reflection API, as follow :

```
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
    def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A]) = {
        request match {
            case specificRequest : Request[SpecificRequest] if (typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[SpecificRequest]) => // Do the request processing
        }
}
```

That should allow you to retrieve the type, and be able to call specific methods on it.